# How to get old top news?

Tags: machine-learning

I am not sure this is the right forum to ask.

For a machine learning training, I need a dataset of old top news by keywords that can be organized by date. From where I can download it? I have seen that Google News API can provide only real time news.

Comment: I think [Open Data SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) is a better site. From their [Help Center](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): _If you have a question about …•where to find any kind of open data •specific open data sets …_

Comment: The OP should as well post it in datascience community.